# Recycler View: How do I set a custom animation for item change (notifyItemChanged)

Tags: android

I would like to override the DefaultItemAnimator but be able to set the animation of item changes (via calls to notifyItemChanged) to my own one, i attempted to research this and i looked at the documentation but it seems you can only set the duration of the animations . Please help

Comment: `mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator` ?

Answer (score 0):

From the DefaultItemAnimator class documentation:

```
/**
 * This implementation of {@link com.twotoasters.android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ItemAnimator} provides basic
 * animations on remove, add, and move events that happen to the items in
 * a RecyclerView. RecyclerView uses a DefaultItemAnimator by default.
 *
 * @see com.twotoasters.android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView#setItemAnimator(com.twotoasters.android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ItemAnimator)
 */
```

Creating custom remove, add or move animations can be easily done by overriding the `animateRemobeImpl()`, `animateAddImpl()` and `animateMoveImpl()` methods. However, change animations are not implemented on this class.

One possible solution would be to subclass `DefaultItemAnimator` and create instance variables related to change animations, using those variables the same way as the remove, add and move variables, something like:

```
private ArrayList<ViewHolder> mPendingChanges = new ArrayList<ViewHolder>();
private ArrayList<ViewHolder> mChangeAnimations = new ArrayList<ViewHolder>();
```